How to Show a Dialog After Popping the Current Context in Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter app and I have a function that performs several tasks after logging in, including popping the current context and then showing a dialog. However, I'm running into an issue where the dialog does not appear because the context has already been popped.
Code:
Future<void> _confirmLoginPassword() async {
    await _downloadAll();
    HolupUserProvider _userProvider = Provider.of<HolupUserProvider>(
        context, listen: false);
    HolupReleaseInfoProvider _releaseProvider =
    Provider.of<HolupReleaseInfoProvider>(context, listen: false);
    String? _lastSeenRelease = DateTime.now().toIso8601StringFormatted();
    double height = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .height;

    if (mounted) {
      List<HolupReleaseInfo>? releaseFeatures = _releaseProvider.findNewerReleases(
          _userProvider.profile?.lastSeenRelease ?? DateTime.now());

      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      showHolupToast("Si prihlásený");

      if (releaseFeatures == null) {
        _downloadNewReleaseInfo(_releaseProvider);
      }

      if (releaseFeatures != null && releaseFeatures.isNotEmpty) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          showHolupBottomDialog(
            context,
            HolupBottomSheet(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 24, horizontal: 205),
              title: "Novinky v Holupovi",
              child: ReleaseInfoList(
                showLatestReleaseOnly: false,
              ),
              height: height - 64,
            ),
          );

          NewReleaseApi.updateLastSeenRelease(
              _userProvider.baseNumber!, _lastSeenRelease,
              _userProvider.token!);

          _releaseProvider.show = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

The Issue:
When I call Navigator.of(context).pop(), it pops the current context, but then when I try to show the dialog immediately afterward, I get an error because the context has been unmounted.
Error:
This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
What I Need:
I need a reliable way to show a dialog immediately after popping the current context in the same function. How can I achieve this? Or any other way how to show dialog after some function, not dependant on context.

The solution would be similar to:
AlertDialog without context in Flutter
What you can do is set a globalKey for the navigator/MaterialApp
for example, in your first screen, add a navigatorKey:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // add this line
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

and then use that key in the second screen:
void _popAndShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    showDialog(
      context: MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext!, // --> Use the key here
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Dialog'),
          content: Text('This dialog should appear after popping.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  });
}


Here is a complete runnable snippet to demonstrate, it will show a dialog after 3 seconds of popping:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('First Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Go to Second Screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Second Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Pop and Show Dialog'),
          onPressed: () {
            _popAndShowDialog(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _popAndShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      showDialog(
        context: MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Dialog'),
            content: Text('This dialog should appear after popping.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Close'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }
}


